# Popup with a blur around it

Tags: qt, qml

This is a question partially related to this one: [Cast a shadow with Popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51554005/cast-a-shadow-with-popup)

I have the same MWE as there. In addition to casting shadow, the Popup should blur everything in the main window. The question is, either I can blur something that is not an image, but for example a Text property?

Answer (score 1):

You could do that with the [`overlay.modal`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.9/qml-qtquick-controls2-applicationwindow.html#overlay-prop) property of `ApplicationWindow` (or the `Overlay.modal` attached property of your popup in Qt 5.10+).
It defines a component to be used and instantiated when a model `Popup` is opened, (similarly, there's a `modeless` component property for popups with `dim: true` but `modal: false`).

This translate to this in your example:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    width: 400
    height: 400
    visible: true

    Rectangle {
        id: rectMain;
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height

        Canvas {
            anchors.fill: parent

            property real hue: 0
            RotationAnimation on hue {
                from: 0
                to: 360
                duration: 4000
                running: true
                loops: Animation.Infinite
            }
            onHueChanged: requestPaint()
            onPaint: {
                var ctx = getContext("2d");
                ctx.fillStyle = Qt.hsla(hue / 360, 1, 0.5, 1);
                ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
            }
        }
        Button {
            text: "Open"
            onClicked: popup.open()
        }

        Popup {
            id: popup

            x: 100
            y: 100
            width: 200
            height: 300
            modal: true
            focus: true
            closePolicy: Popup.CloseOnEscape | Popup.CloseOnPressOutside

            // new attached property in 5.10, in 5.9 and older use the overlay.modal property of ApplicationWindow.
            Overlay.modal: GaussianBlur {
                source: ShaderEffectSource { // you can just do source: window.contentItem if you just want a live blur.
                    sourceItem: window.contentItem
                    live: false
                }
                radius: 8
                samples: 16
            }

            padding: 0

            Rectangle {
                id: popRect;
                color: "red";

                width: parent.width
                height: parent.height
            }

            background: DropShadow {
                source: popup.contentItem

                horizontalOffset: 0
                verticalOffset: 5
                radius: 10
                samples: 7
                color: "black"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but I think it doesnt work. Turning on the example and looking at the application when the popup is on, the text on the underneath button is not blurred at all.

Comment: I guess you are using Qt 5.10 or later then (I just assumed you were using 5.9 from your import versions). For it to work on 5.10, you need to bump the import version of `QtQuick.Controls` to 2.3, and use `Overlay.modal: GaussianBlur { ... }` in your `Popup` (note that it is now `Overlay` with a capital O, it's an attached property) and not in the `ApplicationWindow`.

Comment: Would you mind updating the example? It still does not work for me.

Comment: So I tested it and the problem is the following: Each time someting changes in the main window (for example I redraw a canvas) the bluer is reaplied. Second thing is, that while the canvas is redrawn, it is not visible from under the blur. Thats why I was wondering either something like  "blurring glass" is possible to implement?

Comment: Have you tried the code from my second snipper, with `ShaderEffectSource` and `live: false` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177018/discussion-between-grecko-and-bremen).

Comment: Unfortunately, `ApplicationWindow.contentItem` does not include window's header, footer etc., so using it as a source and stretching the result across the whole `Overlay.modal` may produce incorrect results

Comment: @ratijas as a workaround you could use `ApplicationWindow.contentItem.parent`, that should include everything. At least it did when I tried that a couple years ago.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, here is an example:

```
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.1
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0

ApplicationWindow
{
    id: window
    width: 400
    height: 400
    visible: true

    Rectangle
    {
        id: rectMain;
        width: parent.width;
        height: parent.height;

        Button
        {
            text: "Open"
            onClicked: popup.open()
        }

        Popup
        {
            id: popup

            x: 100
            y: 100
            width: 200
            height: 300
            modal: true
            focus: true
            closePolicy: Popup.CloseOnEscape | Popup.CloseOnPressOutside

            leftPadding: 0;
            rightPadding: 0;
            topPadding: 0;
            bottomPadding: 0;

            Rectangle
            {
                id: popRect;
                color: "red";

                //anchors.centerIn: parent
                width: parent.width;
                height: parent.height;
            }

            DropShadow
            {
                width: popup.width;
                height: popup.height;

                source: popRect;

                horizontalOffset: 0;
                verticalOffset: 5;
                radius: 10;
                samples: 7;
                color: "black";
            }

            onOpened: theBlur.visible = true;
            onClosed: theBlur.visible = false;
        }

        GaussianBlur
        {
            id: theBlur;
            visible: false;
            anchors.fill: rectMain;
            source: rectMain;
            radius: 8
            samples: 16
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to go even more fancy, you could switch to opacity instead of visible and add a `Behaviour on opacity { NumberAnimation { duration: 200 } }`

Comment: Also note, there is FastBlur, which supposedly is faster ;-)

Comment: I have just noticed that this is not quite the functionality i was looking for. What I meant more, is to create a "glass sheet" covering my whole window. This sheet could be 100% transparent. When popup is opened, it could become blurry, for all the components under it. Would this be possible?

Comment: I have it working now, but of course part of a bigger project, so not easy to share.
I think you should move the GaussianBlur outside of the Rectangle and change the blur property `anchor.fill: parent`

Comment: The problem is different: I can blur what is underneath the popup, but the elements there (on that parent rectangle) are dynamic. because of that, each time something changes, the blur is reaplied... I am looking for a solution that would blur everything under a rectangle, with the feature, that in case anything changes under that blurring rectangle, the blur is not reaplied.

Comment: hmm I see, not the suspected case ;-) I'm not sure, but maybe `cached: true` can help, maybe it works to toggle that property when you need a refresh?